# case inside values statement

Tags: postgresql

I want to insert data from mysql into a table in postgresql. I want to perform a WHERE NOT EXISTS statement for a particular id.

```
   # Source data: MySQL
   curr_msql.execute(''' SELECT code, subjectname 
                          FROM test_subj ''')

    # Target data: PostgreSQL
    for row in curr_msql:
            curr_psql.execute(''' INSERT INTO subs (
                                                    created, modified,
                                                    subjcode, subjname,
                                                    is_pe_or_nstp)

                                  VALUES (current_timestamp, current_timestamp,
                                          %s, %s,
                                          %s) ''', (row['code'], row['subjectname'],
False))
```

I want to know how can I replace the "False" to a case statement. Something like

```
CASE
    WHEN code like '%PE%' or code like '%NSTP%'
    THEN True
    ELSE False
END
```

I tried to run this code:

```
for row in curr_msql:
            curr_psql.execute(''' INSERT INTO subs (
                                                    created, modified,
                                                    subjcode, subjname,
                                                    is_pe_or_nstp)

                                  VALUES (current_timestamp, current_timestamp,
                                          %s, %s,
                                          CASE
        WHEN code like '%PE%' or code like '%NSTP%'
        THEN True
        ELSE False
    END) ''', (row['code'], row['subjectname']))
```

I'm getting `IndexError: tuple out of index` error message
Any advice pls?

- The destination DB is PostgreSQL, source data is from MySQL.

Comment: Perform CASE on the client level, not on SQL server level. Client knows the value of `row['code']` and can calculate the value You need to insert.

Comment: Another way is to use `INSERT .. SELECT` instead of `INSERT .. VALUES`. SELECT part allows calculations You need... but You will have to transfer the value of `row['code']` twice - for `subjcode` field and for statement to calculate `is_pe_or_nstp` separately.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ the destination DB is PostgreSQL source data is from MySQL

Comment: Have you considered using a prepared statement instead?

Comment: @Lennart not yet. I'm a newbie, this is by far the farthest I go but would love to explore that too.

Comment: @tangoward, I think you will find that the code becomes cleaner. In addition you avoid potential sql-injection and the DBMS don't have to compile every new statement.

Comment: @Lennart my current situation requires to parse every data per row. I find the current code flexible but again I am still willing to learn new approach.

Answer (score 5):

One part of your problem is that `execute()` tries to interpret the `LIKE` expressions (`'%PE%'`) as a placeholder.  You have to double all the percent signs, so that the following query in pure SQL (with a pseudocode placeholder)

```
SELECT ? WHERE 'abc' LIKE '%bc'
```

turns into

```
cur.execute("SELECT %s WHERE 'abc' LIKE '%%bc'", ['%s'])
cur.fetchall()
==> [('%s',)]
```

Since the column `code` is also from the source table, it needs to be "fed" from the parameters, too.

```
for row in curr_msql:
    curr_psql.execute(''' 
        INSERT INTO subs (
                           created, modified,
                           subjcode, subjname,
                           is_pe_or_nstp )
        VALUES (current_timestamp, current_timestamp,
                %s, %s,
                CASE
                    WHEN %s LIKE %s OR %s LIKE %s
                    THEN TRUE
                    ELSE FALSE
                END) 
    ''', (row['code'], row['subjectname'], 
          row['code'], '%PE%', 
          row['code'], '%NSTP%'))
```

and much cleaner, using named parameters:

```
for row in curr_msql:
    param = dict(code = row['code'], 
                 subjectname = row['subjectname'], 
                 str1 = '%PE%', 
                 str2 = '%NSTP%')
    curr_psql.execute(''' 
        INSERT INTO subs (
                           created, modified,
                           subjcode, subjname,
                           is_pe_or_nstp )
        VALUES (current_timestamp, current_timestamp,
                %(code)s, %(subjectname)s,
                CASE
                    WHEN %(code)s LIKE %(str1)s OR %(code)s LIKE %(str2)s
                    THEN TRUE
                    ELSE FALSE
                END) 
    ''', param)
```

Link to psycopg2: [Basic module usage](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html) for further reading.

Comment: I'll try this when I get to office by Monday. I'll update you guys.

Comment: Holy sheet this works! By the way, when I used named parameters. I am getting integer error. Is it okay to use a combination of keys for rows and index number? From what I read on other threads, I should be using row[<index number>].